# Python tzwhere - tzNameAt missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python

Quick issue: This code snippet below gives me a type error:

"TypeError: tzNameAt missing 1 required positional argument: 'longitude'"

```
from tzwhere import tzwhere

TimeZone = tzwhere.tzwhere.tzNameAt(37.3880961, -5.9823299)
```

Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tzwhere):

```
>>> from tzwhere import tzwhere
>>> tz = tzwhere.tzwhere()
>>> print tz.tzNameAt(37.3880961, -5.9823299)
```

Comment: Ah! Missed the parentheses! Thank you!